# Is there any reason to use await and async right away?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I found this code on the net.

```
    If request.Content IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Hash content to ensure message integrity
        Using md5__1 = MD5.Create()
            requestContentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(md5__1.ComputeHash(Await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
        End Using
    End If
```

The whole point of doing some asynchronous thingy is so that something else can be done first while waiting for the asynchronous thingy to finish.

So

```
dim task = somethingasync()
doSomething
await task
```

would make sense

But `await somethingasync` doesn't make any sense to me. What's the point? You're not doing anything anyway. You wait till somethingasync complete anyway.

In fact, even

```
dim task = somethingasync()
doSomething
await task
```

Stuff that contains await operator should not be on main UI thread right? That's because we don't want user to wait.

Here is the thing. If the whole thing happens in non main UI thread what is the point of making that whole thing wait for result?

Why not use the synchronous version?

Comment: Your snippet must be coming from backend environment. In single-threaded  asynchronous model, like Node.JS for instance, this makes a perfect sense (in order to allow simultaneous incoming requests to be processed while you're waiting for async operation). But in multi-threaded, like .NET? No idea. May be someone just was not paying enough attention while was writing this code.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser in multi-threaded model the thread can be returned to the threadpool and do some other stuff, e.g. serve other request, etc while waiting for the I/O operation to finish. Blocking a thread means blocking a resource while it can be useful somewhere else.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean your code can do something else - it usually means that the UI thread can process updates at the same time to keep your app responsive while waiting for the `await` code to complete.

Comment: It looks like `somethingasync` takes some time to finish its task and the thread that invoke it needs to return the control to another thread or task without wait for the end of this task (`somethingasync`). This kind of programming is useful to avoid waste the resourses, as  threads, as @DiligentKeyPresser told you. Also, this technic helps to avoid bottle necks.

Comment: The code is from a [_web environment_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) - re: http `request` so the request can be put back in the pool while something else is doing something. The code though doesn't look like it _has_ to be (unless there's more to it - re: async all the way)/

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about what await does. It does not block the current thread, quite the opposite. It’s basically a way to make registration of a bunch of callbacks *look* like traditional procedural code. await basically says “start this operation, then when it’s finished, pickup back here where you left off”, in the meantime the thread is free to execute other things.

Answer (score 1):

Check your function:

You can do asynchronous operation in async function:

```
//Wrong
void AsyncCallFunc()
    {
        AsyncFunc();
        //doSomething
    }

//Correct
async void TrueAsyncCallFunc()
    {
        await AsyncFunc();
        //doSomething
    }
```

Additionally, if you surround it with try-catch, you can optionally add your final operation inside a finally. It will run right after all of your operation inside try:

```
async void TrueAsyncCallFunc()
    {
        try{
            await AsyncFunc();
            //doSomething
        }
        catch(Exception){
            throw;
        }
        finally{
            //do last operation
        }
    }
```